# List subdirectory contents with date created/modified in CMD

Tags: cmd, ls, dir

In short: In Windows CMD, I need to list all the contents in all of the sub-directories of a folder, and their `date-created` or `date-modified` timestamps.

**In long:**

I want to regularly run a command which outputs the creation datetimes of files we upload to our FTP. I'm able to do this for one folder at a time and get the output in a text file (dir . **h:\uploadtimes.txt**). I'd like to do this for over 100 folders in one go. Filename and datetime-created is all I need.

THANKS!

Comment: In resume: what have you tried so far?

Comment: This command - dir . h:\uploadtimes.txt - does what I want for one folder. I can't seem to do this recursively. I've tried "ls -ilR" but that does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`dir /?` could help (or read [command reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx)); one could use `/TC` switch instead of `/TW` one:

```
dir X:\folder\*.* /S /A-D /-C /TW > h:\uploadtimes.txt
```

Another approach giving fully qualified file names but always `date-modified` timestamp regardless of `/T` switch unfortunately:

```
for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir X:\folder\*.* /S /B /A-D') do @echo %G %~TG > h:\uploadtimes.txt
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)